# In what sense is Pade aproximation "best"

Tags: polynomials, approximation, nonlinear-optimization, rational-functions, pade-approximation

The wikipedia article on Pade approximations says that its the "best" rational approximation of a given function but doesn't elaborate further. I've seen some form of this claim posted around the internet but I can't seem to find anyone that defines whats meant by "best" here.

Pade approximation is often compared to Taylor series expansion and truncation but [as I recently learned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135543/does-taylor-series-expansion-minimize-maximum-error-for-polynomial-aproximation) Taylor series expansion isn't actually ideal. How does Pade approximation compare to Chebyshev approximation? Is Pade approximation actually the best rational aproximation in terms of the uniform norm?

If Pade approximation is not truly the best, what are good techniques for solving the following problem:

Given an "well behaved" (take your pick of regularity constraints here) function $f$ and a range $[a, b]$ find two polynomials $P$ and $Q$ of degree $n$ and $m$ respectively such the the following norm is minimized:

$$\max_{x \in [a, b]}{\lvert f(x) - \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} \rvert}$$

That feels like the most natural definition of "best" to me personally. What literature exists for this problem?

Comment: The sense in which it is best is similar to the sense in which Taylor is best. The $n$-th Taylor polynomial $T_n$ is the polynomial, among those of degree at most $n$ that makes $f-T_n$ be in the smallest $o(x^k)$ as $x\to0$. The Pade approximant $P_{n,m}$ is the rational function with numerator of degree at most $n$ and denominator at most $m$ that make $f-P_{n,m}$ be in the smallest $o(x^k)$ as $x\to 0$. As you see, in both it is a local condition.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me, but a book that I would check is "Rational Approximations and Orthogonality" by E. M. Nikishin and V. N. Sorokin . It concerns that type of problems.